# Antivirus for Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, anti-virus

I need to find antivirus for Windows 2003 server. I only have one server. Does anyone know how I can buy the software for just one server (no workstations) for around $50 is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Symantec Corporate Edition antivirus and it isn't terribly riddled with bloat like the consumer Norton packages.  Eset has a pretty solid antivirus package but you can't get it for Windows Server at that price.  Is this just for a file server?  AVG File Server Edition is good and you can get it for $99/year for a server with five connections.  I've used this successfully on Workstations and it had kept my machines clean and running smoothly.

Comment: Can I buy just ONE seat?

Comment: I would check their website for the different packages and offerings.

Comment: Avg has a server antivirus with 5 connections for $99.

Answer (score 4):

I can't give you advice on which antivirus to use, but I can tell you which ones NOT to use:
Stay away from McAfee and Norton as they are the most bloat and processor intensive packages I've seen.

I don't have an active monitor running, but I do run a manual virusscan from time to time. I can recommend [Kasperksy](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner) for this (they're free for scanning).

Comment: Yes, they're now bloated, no doubt. But in their defense, they are moving towards HIPS (actually, they are there) since signature-based detection is falling further behind.

Comment: I use Kaspersky AntiVirus 2009 on my Windows XP, however it won't install on Win2003 server. They require KS AntiVirus For File Server, at $290 a pop. way too much....

Answer (score 2):

We recently switched long-time-use Symantec AntiVirus to TrendMicro, and I am glad I did it. It has various options you can choose to secure your system and the price is cheap. We choose Worry-Free Enterprise, which costs around $23 per node.  Definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I used about a year [BitDefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/PRODUCT-33-en--BitDefender-v1.9-for-File-Servers.html)
After that We stooped using NetBios and folder sharing So I now run without any antivirus system.
I can said that is most of my requirements was above the expected for this product.

**But I still wondering**
Do We need antivirus system for servers. 
If it only run on services such as SQL, IIS and others

Answer (score 0):

I understand that **clamav** is available for windows.  Not sure about server 2003, but worth a look.

I use it on Linux machines all the time, and it's free.

Comment: Only thing about clamav is it can't fix a file, only quarantine or delete.  Then again, SAV is supposed to be able to, but I've never once seen it successfully clean a file, it always quarantines or deletes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you use and if you need it depends on the use and exposure of the server.  If you have a lot of client machines hitting it you probably should have something installed. Take your pick, they all have good and bad.

Answer (score 0):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com/) should cover your needs.